# Why Json.NET cannot deserialize JSON arrays into object property?

Tags: c#, json.net

**Temporary note: This is NOT a duplicate of the above mentioned post**

Let's say I have a server-side class structure like this.

```
public class Test
{
    // this can be any kind of "Tag"
    public object Data { get; set; }
}

public class Other
{
    public string Test { get; set; }
}
```

Now a string like this is coming from let's say the client.

```
{"Data": [{$type: "MyProject.Other, MyProject", "Test": "Test"}] }
```

When I try to deserialize this into a `Test` instance, I get a result where the `Tag` property is a `JToken` instead of some kind of collection, for example `ArrayList` or `List<object>`.

I understand that `Json.NET` cannot deserialize into a strongly typed list, but I'd expect that it respects that it's at least a list.

Here is my current deserialization code.

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings()
{
    TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto,
};

var str = "{\"Data\": [{\"$type\": \"MyProject.Other, MyProject\", \"Test\": \"Test\"}] }";
var test = JsonConvert.Deserialize<Test>(str, settings);

// this first assertion fails
(test.Data is IList).ShouldBeTrue();
(((IList)test.Data)[0] is Other).ShouldBeTrue();
```

I'm aware of the fact that if I serialize such a structure, then by default I'll get a `{ $type: ..., $values: [...]}` structure in the JSON string instead of a pure array literal, and that will indeed properly deserialize. However, the client is sending a pure array literal, so I should be able to handle that in some way.

Comment: Did you use `JsonSerializerSettings` and specify typehandling? In any case, if you want to ask "why doesn't my code work" you need to post your code, so post the deserialization code.

Comment: How should it know that `object` should be a `List<Other>` in this case? Should it try to match the received JSON against all fitting types in the assembly? That would be very slow and would not yield any stable result.

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21470697/how-to-deserialize-an-untyped-object-using-json-net-or-datacontractjsonserialize

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deserialize Dictionary<string, object> with enum values in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38336390/deserialize-dictionarystring-object-with-enum-values-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Edited, removed the `Dictionary<string, object>` part entirely because my problem is reproducible without that too. Hope now it will get less criticism and more constructive thoughts.

Comment: Could anyone please remove the duplicate label, and also the one who downvoted, could you please remove it, or at least add some reasons?

Comment: I never deserialized JSON, but why do you expect something that is deserialized to be mutable and an `IList<>`? I would have expected it to be `IEnumerable<>` (not sure if it is) and nothing more.

Comment: @nvoigt That's worth another discussion I think. In the scope of this question it doesn't matter, I'd just expect *a collection*. By the way as JSON is "coming" from JavaScript, I associate `[ ... ]` literal in the JSON as an *array*. And arrays in JavaScript are just very similar to `IList` interface, that's why I mentioned `IList`. But as I said, it doesn't matter, I'd be happy with `IEnumerable`.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to put together a `JsonConverter` to handle these kind of untyped lists. The converter applies when the target type is `object`. Then if the current token type is array start (`[`) it will force a deserialization into `List<object>`. In any other case it will fall back to *normal* deserialization.

This is a first version which passes my most important unit tests, however as I'm not a `Json.NET` expert, it might break some things unexpectedly. Please if anyone sees anything what I didn't, leave a comment.

```
public class UntypedListJsonConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanWrite => false;
    public override bool CanRead => true;

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType != JsonToken.StartArray)
        {
            return serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        }

        return serializer.Deserialize<List<object>>(reader);
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(object);
    }
}
```

Usage example:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings()
{
    TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto,
    Converters = new[] { new UntypedListJsonConverter() }
};

var str = "{\"Data\": [{\"$type\": \"MyProject.Other, MyProject\", \"Test\": \"Test\"}] }";
var test = JsonConvert.Deserialize<Test>(str, settings);
// now these assertions pass
(test.Data is IList).ShouldBeTrue();
(((IList)test.Data)[0] is Other).ShouldBeTrue();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public class Test
{
    public Dictionary<string, List<Other>> Data { get; } = new Dictionary<string, List<Other>>();
}
```

You need to set up the class you are trying to fill from json data to match as closely to the json structure. From the looks of it, the json looks a dictionary where the keys are strings and the values are arrays of `Other` objects.

Comment: Thank you, of course if I could I would do it this way, but using an `object` value is intentional. The dictionary is kind of a custom property holder, hence it could contains almost anything.